# Kentico CMS - how to add link in footer?

Tags: kentico

i know nothing about Kentico but i want to add a backlink to the footer of the website sidewide, can somebody please guide me how to do that via directory folders in plesk, which file do i need to edit? etc?  help would be much appreciated

[kentico direcotry at plesk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Af4cx.png)

Answer (score 1):

Plesk is for administrating the project files which run on the web server. In this case, those are ASP.NET application code files, not the content of your web site. Well, unless you are using physical ASPX page templates. I would recommend to [log into Kentico admin](https://docs.kentico.com/k12sp/using-the-kentico-interface) through the web browser and edit the master page to add the link. You should get either more familiar with Kentico and at least read the docs on [how to edit the content](https://docs.kentico.com/k12sp/managing-website-content/working-with-pages) or assign this task to your web admins/developers or content editors.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable feedback, if the website is running physical ASPX page template, then how can i check it ?

Comment: Then you need to find the page template on the disk where you want to add the link. It is either ASPX page template or maybe master page template. Please see this section of the docs: https://docs.kentico.com/k12sp/developing-websites/developing-websites-using-aspx-templates